# sed editing a line

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use `sed` to modify a line like below

```
CustomLog /home/logs/httpd/access_log common
```

to

```
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /home/logs/httpd/access_log_%m_%d_%Y 86400" combined
```

I tried `sed` replace with text and it didn't work. I'm trying to do this for around 800 files, so need a single command to do this.

Comment: could you paste the line that you have tried? Maybe it was a simple mistake that we will be able to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\1 "|\/usr\/sbin\/rotatelogs \2_`date +%m_%d_%Y` 86400" combined/'
```

Example:

```
> echo "CustomLog /home/logs/httpd/access_log common" | sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\1 "|\/usr\/sbin\/rotatelogs \2_`date +%m_%d_%Y` 86400" combined/'
```

Comment: This just worked for me aswell after trying for so many time.

sed -e 's/CustomLog/\CustomLog "|\/usr\/sbin\/rotatelogs/' -e 's/_log/_log_%m_%d_%Y 86400"/' filename(i used * for filename so that i can use it for all files in my directory)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i.bak '/CustomLog/{
        s# # "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs #
        s/ common$/_%m_%d_%Y 86400" combined/
}' *.conf
```